# Problem Referencing a Function in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to use List.Generate to loop through a number of API calls.  I am running, though, into a problem.  Here is my code:

## Steps Taken

### Step #1 - Create a list of stock symbols

[image]

### Step #2 - Get a Count of That List

[image]

### Step #3 -- Use List.Generate to loop through the Stock Symbols:

[image]

Here is the code I used to generate the list:

```
= List.Generate(
    () => [index = 0, ticker = Source{index} ],
    each [index] < SourceCount,
    each [index = [index] + 1, ticker = Source{index} ]
)
```

### Step #4 -- Create a Function in Another Query

In addition, I have another query that is a function which queries an API call.  Here is the code for that function:

```
= (tickerSymbol) => 

let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://[WORKSPACE].iex.cloud/v1/data/core/income/" & tickerSymbol & "/annual?range=10y&token=[API_KEY]"))
in
    Source
```

This function works. I have tested it out.

### Step #5 -- Put it All Together

Now, I want to use that function within List.Generate (from my first query).  To do this, I rewrite the List.Generate function I mentioned above as follows:

```
= List.Generate(
    () => [index = 0, ticker = Source{index}, stockData = getStockData(ticker) ],
    each [index] < SourceCount,
    each [index = [index] + 1, ticker = Source{index}, stockData = getStockData([ticker]) ]
)
```

## The Problem

It is at this point that I run into a proble.  When I try to modify List.Generate as mentioned above, I get the following error message:

> Formula.Firewall: Query 'Query1' (step 'GenerateList') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.

[image]

Now, I am basically following this tutorial step by step:  https://youtu.be/a_RJzoj1cnM

In the tutorial it works, but in my variation of the tutorial it does not.  I should note, I am new to Power Query and am not sure what the warning message means.

Either way, any idea what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be very convoluted

Cant you just pull in the Symbols as source, convert list to table, then add a new custom column with formula

```
= getStockData([ColumnNameOfStockSymbolsHere])
```

Comment: Very nice, that did it.

Comment: I would still like to know why I got the error, when in the tutorial I watched everything seemed to work fine.  But, nonetheless, this solved my problem in a very nice and easy-to-implement manner.  Thanks.